# how to convert unix epoch microseconds into Java time stamp

Tags: java, unix

Epoch time in MicroSeconds : 1529948813696000

how to convert this into java time stamp.

I am able to convert epoch time in MilliSeconds using this method

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong("1529957592000"));
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).toString())
```

Need help to convert Epoch time in Microseconds ?

Comment: You shouldn’t be using Strings and formats just to convert an Instant to a Date.  Just use `Date parsedDate = Date.from(instant);`.  Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#from%28java.time.Instant%29).

Answer (score 7):

While the `Instant` class doesn't have an `ofEpochNano(long)` method, it does has an overload of [`ofEpochSecond(long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-) that accepts a nanosecond offset along with the epoch seconds.

With a little math you can just convert your epoch microseconds to seconds plus an offset and create your `Instant` using it, like so:

```
long epochMicroSeconds = 1_529_948_813_696_123L;
long epochSeconds = epochMicroSeconds / 1_000_000L;
long nanoOffset = ( epochMicroSeconds % 1_000_000L ) * 1_000L ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( epochSeconds, nanoOffset ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mrWGUO).

> instant.toString(): 2018-06-25T17:46:53.696123Z

Comment: Yah, I was spacing between millis and micros for a bit, needed to update the math.  I should know better than to post code without running it through a debugger first... :p